# How to apply sw_glance using mutate_at to nested time-series dataframe?

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, broom

I am forecasting several models on a nested (grouped) df. My issue is solved if I apply sw_glance to each list-column separately, but, for my example, if I am applying 6 models, then it is asking me to mutate six times. I have spent countless hours and I think I am almost there. Why can't I do the line below and overwrite the existing variables with the new values the function brings? (I included a reprex below, where step 5 is where I am getting stuck)

```
models_df%<>% map(~mutate_at(.x,vars(mod_ets,mod_hw)),sw_glance)
```

Just to name a few, here is the list:

-tidyverse documentation, where it mentioned that for grouped variables, `mutate_at` would fail, unless I add `-group_cols()`. No go.

-purrr documentation: I tried `pmap` passing a list of variables. I tried map in combination with `mutate_at`. I tried `mutate_at` by itself. I have tried naming the function (.f ...)  and anonymous one (~..), but nothing

-I tried here several articles, that almost got me there.
I upgraded to tidyr 1.0 and can include my sessionInfo() if needed.

```
#1 dummy df
df=tibble(Tag=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),by="month", length.out = 60), gatos=sample(c("a","b"),60, replace = T), sales=runif(60))

#2 nesting 
nested_df= df %>% 
  group_by(gatos) %>% 
  nest()

#3 declaring time series
ts_vector = nested_df %>%
  mutate(data.ts=map(data,tk_ts,select=-Tag,start=c(2010,01),freq=12))

# Step 4: Apply models
models_df = ts_vector %>% 
  mutate(mod_ets = map(data.ts,ets),
         mod_hw = map(data.ts,HoltWinters))

# Step 5: Apply sw_glance (Does NOT work)
models_df %<>%
map(~mutate_at(.x,vars(mod_ets,mod_hw)),sw_glance)

Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"

# This DOES work
models_df %<>% 
  mutate(foo_ets=map(mod_ets,sw_glance),
         foo_hw=map(mod_hw,sw_glance))
```

I would expect that `mutate_at` modifies the existing variables without having to add new ones. Otherwise, I would appreciate how to apply `sw_glance` to several models in one-go if possible. Thank you guys. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is `tk_ts` ?

Comment: @Ronak : Essential and basic function for time series coercion part of timetk package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a function to apply `sw_glance` to each model

```
library(tidyverse)

apply_models <- function(list_model) map(list_model, sweep::sw_glance)
```

and apply it to multiple columns using `mutate_at`

```
models_df %>% mutate_at(vars(mod_ets, mod_hw), apply_models)

#  gatos           data data.ts mod_ets           mod_hw           
#  <chr> <list<df[,2]>> <list>  <list>            <list>           
#1 b           [31 × 2] <ts>    <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 12]>
#2 a           [29 × 2] <ts>    <tibble [1 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 12]>
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak! Thank you very much for this approach. While it works, it creates more columns. Above in my text I mentioned I was looking to affect/replace(let's call it overwrite) mod_ets and mod_hw with the new values that sw_glance would bring once we apply that function. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: @Will ohh..I thought you were specifically looking for new columns in your original dataframe. In that case, you can do `models_df %>%  mutate_at(vars(mod_ets, mod_hw), apply_models)`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: ! I just modified the text by removing the "foo" from the function and now it works by overwriting the two current variables. So, that's taken care of. Any thoughts as to why I cannot just apply the sw_glance directly and have to write a function instead?

Comment: It seems you were responding when I was telling about it...lol :)

Comment: `sw_glance` accepts only one model at a time. As we are passing multiple models (column) to it we need to use `map` (or `lapply`) which will pass each model one at a time.

Comment: In other words, sw_glance can only take one model (i.e one column) at a time and therefore, to make it accepts more than one model, the columns (mod_ets and mod_hw) needed to be converted to a list, is that right? Now, I was using map to loop through each row of the columns specified within mutate_at.

Comment: No..not exactly. One column != one model. In fact, for every column we have multiple models i.e equal to number of rows. For the example shared, we have got 2 models each in column `mod_ets` and `mod_hw`. Using `mutate_at`, we are looping over each column mentioned in `vars` and with `map` we are looping over  each value in those columns.

Comment: Outstanding Ronak! Thank you very much for your wisdom. Problem successfully solved!